# Why does this javascript inheritance cause references to share array?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

i have a base class

```
function Base(){
    this.children = new Array();
}
Base.prototype.Add = function(child){
    this.children.push(child)
}

function Sub1(){...}
Sub1.prototype = new Base();

function Sub2(){...}
Sub2.prototype = new Base();
```

so how come when i do

```
var S1_1 = new Sub1();
var S1_2 = new Sub1();
S1_1.Add(new Sub2());
```

S1_2 for some reason also has 1 child and contains the same information as the child i added to S1_1?

Comment: Why are you assigning a `Base` object to `prototype`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because that's how prototypal inheritance works. All your `Sub1` objects inherit from a common `Base` object. Because the `Base` object holds the Array, all `Sub1` instances share that Array.

In other words, when you ask for the `.children` property of each `Sub1` object, they will see that they don't own such a property, and will therefore look for it on the prototype from which they inherit. Since they inherit from the same prototype object, they use the same Array.

---

For each `Sub1` to have its own Array, you should define it in the `Sub1` constructor.

```
function Base(){
    this.children = new Array();
}
Base.prototype.Add = function(child){
    this.children.push(child); // `this` will be whatever object invoked the method
}

function Sub1(){
    this.children = [];
}
Sub1.prototype = new Base();

function Sub2(){
    this.children = [];
}
Sub2.prototype = new Base();
```

Comment: +1 - "Because the Base object holds the Array"

Comment: Better: Set up the inheritance with `Sub1.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);` and call `Base.call(this)` in the child constructors. Using an instance of the parent as prototype only works as long as it does not expect any arguments.

Comment: @FelixKling IE 8 doesn't seem to have Object.create. I've added handling constructor parameters and not calling the "parent" constructor when setting prototype to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 Using goog.inherit

Comment: @HMR For this simple use case, a [basic polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#PolyFill) would be enough.

Comment: @bfavaretto About using polyfill, it changes `for(hh in Object){` in this case maybe not so importaint but the reason why google uses `goog.array.peek = function` instead of Array.prototype.peek. If you polyfil `.create` for Object then `create` will show up in for(hh in myObject)

Comment: @HMR No, it won't show up in `for(hh in myObject)`, only in  `for(hh in Object)`. It's added as an own property of the Object constructor.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes you are correct, it will show up in instances when you add it to `Object.prototype`. Since `create` is going to be a static property of Object and not going to be on any of it's instances I guess it is save to do so. Where as the forEach example on mdn could result in unexpected behavior for people re using your code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

You didn't take `ownership`/copy of the Base variables defined with `this` when creating a sub, you can do so with:

```
function Sub1(){
  Base.call(this);
}
```

What that code does is calling Base with the Sub1 instance as the `this` context.

More on prototype behavior can be found here: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)